# can feedparser parse geo-rss

Tags: parsing, georss

the [geo-rss.xml](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a) is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<channel>
  <link>http://maps.google.com</link>
  <title>beijing 1</title>
  <description><![CDATA[dsad]]></description>
  <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">00048b5b66b7169311de4</guid>
    <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:23:08 +0000</pubDate>

    <title>ww</title>
    <description><![CDATA[<div dir="ltr">dwqd</div>]]></description>
    <author>zjm1126</author>
    <georss:point>
      39.965015 116.362381
    </georss:point>
    <georss:elev>0.000000</georss:elev>
  </item>

  <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">00048b5b6a51f18e53ea5</guid>
    <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000</pubDate>
    <title>线条 1</title>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <author>zjm1126</author>
    <gml:LineString>

      <gml:posList>
        39.992191 116.417938
        39.968254 116.466698
        39.939568 116.451591
        39.959045 116.411079
      </gml:posList>
    </gml:LineString>
  </item>
  <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">00048b5b6a520c46d52bd</guid>
    <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000</pubDate>

    <title>线条 2</title>
    <description><![CDATA[<br>]]></description>
    <author>zjm1126</author>
    <gml:LineString>
      <gml:posList>
        39.990536 116.437225
        39.963963 116.477051
        39.958702 116.437912
        39.959045 116.411079
      </gml:posList>
    </gml:LineString>

  </item>
  <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">00048b5b6a521daa5391e</guid>
    <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000</pubDate>
    <title>qqdw</title>
    <description><![CDATA[dsa]]></description>
    <author>zjm1126</author>

    <gml:LineString>
      <gml:posList>
        39.987720 116.519913
        39.947990 116.556641
        39.959045 116.523003
      </gml:posList>
    </gml:LineString>
  </item>
  <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">00048b5b6a52357ab39f0</guid>
    <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000</pubDate>

    <title>dwqd</title>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <author>zjm1126</author>
    <gml:Polygon>
      <gml:exterior>
        <gml:LinearRing>
          <gml:posList>
            40.034264 116.451241
            40.015781 116.437225
            40.011654 116.409363
            40.033478 116.430305
            40.034264 116.451241
          </gml:posList>

        </gml:LinearRing>
      </gml:exterior>
    </gml:Polygon>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

and [feedparser](http://www.feedparser.org/) 's code is :

```
import feedparser

class read(BaseRequestHandler):
 def post(self):
  url=self.request.POST['url']
  d = feedparser.parse(url)
  o=d
  self.response.out.write(''.join('%s: %s <br/>' % (a, getattr(o, a)) for a in dir(o)))
  return
```

when i parse geo-rss.xml use feedparser , it show :

```
__class__:
__cmp__:
__contains__:
dwqd
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
dwqd
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'ww', 'language': None}, 'elev': u'0.000000', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b66b7169311de4'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.992191 116.417938\n 39.968254 116.466698\n 39.939568 116.451591\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a51f18e53ea5'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.990536 116.437225\n 39.963963 116.477051\n 39.958702 116.437912\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a520c46d52bd'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'qqdw', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'dsa', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'dsa', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'qqdw', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.987720 116.519913\n 39.947990 116.556641\n 39.959045 116.523003', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a521daa5391e'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'dwqd', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'dwqd', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'40.034264 116.451241\n 40.015781 116.437225\n 40.011654 116.409363\n 40.033478 116.430305\n 40.034264 116.451241', 'exterior': u'', 'polygon': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a52357ab39f0', 'linearring': u''}]}>
__delattr__:
__delitem__:
__dict__: {}
__doc__: None
__eq__:
__ge__:
__getattr__:
dwqd
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
dwqd
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'ww', 'language': None}, 'elev': u'0.000000', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b66b7169311de4'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.992191 116.417938\n 39.968254 116.466698\n 39.939568 116.451591\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a51f18e53ea5'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.990536 116.437225\n 39.963963 116.477051\n 39.958702 116.437912\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a520c46d52bd'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'qqdw', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'dsa', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'dsa', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'qqdw', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.987720 116.519913\n 39.947990 116.556641\n 39.959045 116.523003', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a521daa5391e'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'dwqd', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'dwqd', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'40.034264 116.451241\n 40.015781 116.437225\n 40.011654 116.409363\n 40.033478 116.430305\n 40.034264 116.451241', 'exterior': u'', 'polygon': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a52357ab39f0', 'linearring': u''}]}>
__getattribute__:
__getitem__:
dwqd
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
dwqd
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'ww', 'language': None}, 'elev': u'0.000000', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b66b7169311de4'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.992191 116.417938\n 39.968254 116.466698\n 39.939568 116.451591\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a51f18e53ea5'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.990536 116.437225\n 39.963963 116.477051\n 39.958702 116.437912\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a520c46d52bd'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'qqdw', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'dsa', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'dsa', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'qqdw', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.987720 116.519913\n 39.947990 116.556641\n 39.959045 116.523003', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a521daa5391e'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'dwqd', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'dwqd', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'40.034264 116.451241\n 40.015781 116.437225\n 40.011654 116.409363\n 40.033478 116.430305\n 40.034264 116.451241', 'exterior': u'', 'polygon': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a52357ab39f0', 'linearring': u''}]}>
__gt__:
__hash__:
__init__:
__iter__:
__le__:
__len__:
__lt__:
__module__: feedparser
__ne__:
__new__:
__reduce__:
__reduce_ex__:
__repr__:
__setattr__:
dwqd
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
dwqd
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'ww', 'language': None}, 'elev': u'0.000000', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b66b7169311de4'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.992191 116.417938\n 39.968254 116.466698\n 39.939568 116.451591\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a51f18e53ea5'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.990536 116.437225\n 39.963963 116.477051\n 39.958702 116.437912\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a520c46d52bd'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'qqdw', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'dsa', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'dsa', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'qqdw', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.987720 116.519913\n 39.947990 116.556641\n 39.959045 116.523003', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a521daa5391e'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'dwqd', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'dwqd', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'40.034264 116.451241\n 40.015781 116.437225\n 40.011654 116.409363\n 40.033478 116.430305\n 40.034264 116.451241', 'exterior': u'', 'polygon': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a52357ab39f0', 'linearring': u''}]}>
__setitem__:
dwqd
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
dwqd
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'ww', 'language': None}, 'elev': u'0.000000', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b66b7169311de4'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.992191 116.417938\n 39.968254 116.466698\n 39.939568 116.451591\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a51f18e53ea5'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'\u7ebf\u6761 2', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.990536 116.437225\n 39.963963 116.477051\n 39.958702 116.437912\n 39.959045 116.411079', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a520c46d52bd'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'qqdw', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'dsa', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'dsa', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'qqdw', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'39.987720 116.519913\n 39.947990 116.556641\n 39.959045 116.523003', 'linestring': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a521daa5391e'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'dwqd', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'dwqd', 'language': None}, 'poslist': u'40.034264 116.451241\n 40.015781 116.437225\n 40.011654 116.409363\n 40.033478 116.430305\n 40.034264 116.451241', 'exterior': u'', 'polygon': u'', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b6a52357ab39f0', 'linearring': u''}]}>
__slotnames__: []
__str__:
__weakref__: None
clear:
copy:
fromkeys:
get:
dwqd
', 'language': None}, 'summary': u'
dwqd
', 'guidislink': False, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/plain', 'value': u'ww', 'language': None}, 'elev': u'0.000000', 'id': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/00048b5b66b7169311de4'}, {'updated': u'Wed, 14 Jul 2010 16:24:08 +0000', 'updated_parsed': (2010, 7, 14, 16, 24, 8, 2, 195, 0), 'title': u'\u7ebf\u6761 1', 'author': u'zjm1126', 'summary_detail': {'base': u'http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=255b&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a', 'type': 'text/html', 'value': u'',
```

i want to know , is this data useful for me  ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The patch

http://feedparser.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=-5035140636427960669&name=georss-gml.patch&token=dcfce8c56d5beb3ebf566bc3c16994e2

attached to

http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/issues/detail?id=62

will let you parse GeoRSS of different flavors.