# python feedparser <georss:point>55.32967 10.236263</georss:point>

Tags: python, feedparser

I am trying to the universal feedparser to parse `<georss:point>55.32967 10.236263</georss:point>` but it's not working. I have tried accessing `item['georss']`, `item['georss:point']` and `item['point']` all resulting in a `KeyError`.

I have tried to follow [can feedparser parse geo-rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261610/can-feedparser-parse-geo-rss) but it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the keys for each entry and found that the `georss:point` tag is listed as `georss_point`, so you can call the coordinate value for the entry with either `feed.entry[i].georss_point` or `feed.entry[i]['georss_point']`.

Answer (score 1):

Feedparser does not support georss but there seems to be a patch available at http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/issues/detail?id=62